# How to test failed payments in iOS?

Tags: ios, in-app-billing, storekit

I've had a good Google, but I can only ever find information about people who have errors, not people who want errors.

My IAP appears to be working fine with sandbox test accounts. I'd like to test failed transactions, for example, declined cards.

Can someone please tell me if this is possible?